# Request Timeout when saving an edited entry

Tags: channel-entries, saving

We have a live site that worked ok for some time. Since a day or two we have a strange behavior: when saving some of the entries we get this error

```
Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.
```

There is no error log to be found.

It's EE 5.3 with Publisher.

Is there a way we could find out what would causing the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds server related, perhaps check you have enough memory/RAM and CPU.

Comment: Thank you Bluedreamer. It is on PHP 7.3 with 1GB memory limit. If only we could find out more where it breaks...