# Error when replacing URLs with Deeploy Helper

Tags: deployment

I copy a db from one server to another server and change URL with Deeploy Helper. I get this error message. I also copied to another different server too to double check, and it gives the same error. 
The new URLs are in place and the site seems to work. But I don't feel comfortable.
What could be the reason for this error? 
I might add: it's EE 5.3 / Deeploy Helper 4.2.2

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'item_id' doesn't have a default value:
```

INSERT INTO `exp_revision_tracker` (`item_table`, `item_field`, `item_data`, `item_author_id`, `item_date`) VALUES ('-', 'hop_deeploy_helper', '{\"base_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"site_url\":\"{base_url}\",\"theme_folder_url\":\"{base_url}themes\/\",\"captcha_url\":\"{base_url}images\/captchas\/\",\"captcha_path\":\"{base_path}images\/captchas\/\",\"theme_folder_path\":\"{base_path}themes\/\",\"emoticon_url\":\"{base_url}images\/smileys\/\",\"channel::1::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::1::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::1::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::2::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::2::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::2::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::3::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/downloads-videos\",\"channel::3::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::3::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/downloads-videos\/details\/\",\"channel::4::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/linienverkehr\",\"channel::4::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::4::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/linienverkehr\/details\",\"channel::5::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::5::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::5::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/bedarfsverkehr\/details\",\"channel::6::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::6::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::6::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/eisenbahnverkehr\/details\",\"channel::7::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::7::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::7::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::8::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::8::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::8::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/blaulicht-und-industrie\",\"channel::9::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::9::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::9::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/news\/text\",\"channel::10::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::10::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::10::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::11::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::11::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::11::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/dienstleistungen\",\"channel::12::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::12::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::12::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::13::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::13::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::13::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/unternehmen\",\"channel::14::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::14::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::14::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/qualitaetsmanagement\",\"channel::15::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::15::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::15::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::16::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::16::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::16::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/mitgliedschaften\",\"channel::17::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::17::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::17::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/referenzen\",\"channel::18::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::18::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::18::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/management\",\"channel::19::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::19::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::19::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/events\",\"channel::20::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::20::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::20::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::21::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::21::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::21::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/standorte\",\"channel::22::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::22::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::22::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/kundenservice\",\"channel::23::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::23::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::23::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::24::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::24::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::24::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::25::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::25::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::25::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::26::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::26::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::26::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::27::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::27::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::27::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::28::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::28::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::28::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/karriere\",\"channel::29::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::29::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::29::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/karriere\/offene_stellen\",\"channel::30::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::30::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::30::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/lehrstellen\",\"channel::31::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::31::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::31::search_results_url\":\"\",\"channel::32::channel_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/\",\"channel::32::comment_url\":\"\",\"channel::32::search_results_url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/news\/text\",\"upload_dest::1::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/avatars\/\",\"upload_dest::1::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/avatars\/\",\"upload_dest::2::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/avatars\/default\/\",\"upload_dest::2::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/avatars\/default\/\",\"upload_dest::3::server_path\":\"\/\",\"upload_dest::3::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/member_photos\/\",\"upload_dest::4::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/signature_attachments\/\",\"upload_dest::4::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/signature_attachments\/\",\"upload_dest::5::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/pm_attachments\/\",\"upload_dest::5::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/pm_attachments\/\",\"upload_dest::6::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/uploads\/\",\"upload_dest::6::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/uploads\/\",\"upload_dest::7::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/headers\/\",\"upload_dest::7::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/headers\/\",\"upload_dest::8::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/pdf_docs\/\",\"upload_dest::8::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/pdf_docs\/\",\"upload_dest::9::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/small_headers\/\",\"upload_dest::9::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/small_headers\/\",\"upload_dest::10::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/thumbnails\/\",\"upload_dest::10::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/thumbnails\/\",\"upload_dest::11::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/logos\/\",\"upload_dest::11::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/logos\/\",\"upload_dest::12::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/portraits\/\",\"upload_dest::12::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/portraits\/\",\"upload_dest::13::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/news_media\/\",\"upload_dest::13::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/news_media\/\",\"upload_dest::14::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/medien_downloads\/\",\"upload_dest::14::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/medien_downloads\/\",\"upload_dest::15::server_path\":\"\/home\/octave2s\/public_html\/images\/bildergalerie\/\",\"upload_dest::15::url\":\"https:\/\/www.octave2sbox.ch\/images\/bildergalerie\/\"}', 1, 1578493566)

ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:117
Stack Trace: Please include when reporting this error

```
#0 ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php(112): CI_DB_mysqli_connection->query('INSERT INTO `ex...')
#1 ee/legacy/database/DB_driver.php(270): CI_DB_mysqli_driver->_execute('INSERT INTO `ex...')
#2 ee/legacy/database/DB_driver.php(180): CI_DB_driver->simple_query('INSERT INTO `ex...')
#3 ee/legacy/database/DB_active_rec.php(1371): CI_DB_driver->query('INSERT INTO `ex...')
#4 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Insert.php(75): CI_DB_active_record->insert('revision_tracke...')
#5 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Update.php(99): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Insert->actOnGateway(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\SyntheticGateway), Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Revision\RevisionTracker))
#6 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Insert.php(39): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Update->doWork(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Revision\RevisionTracker))
#7 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Insert.php(27): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Insert->doWork(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Revision\RevisionTracker))
#8 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(282): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Insert->run()
#9 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/DataStore.php(238): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->runQuery('Insert', Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#10 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Query/Builder.php(79): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\DataStore->insertQuery(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder))
#11 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Service/Model/Model.php(355): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Query\Builder->insert()
#12 user/addons/hop_deeploy_helper/mcp.hop_deeploy_helper.php(597): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Service\Model\Model->save()
#13 [internal function]: Hop_deeploy_helper_mcp->save()
#14 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Addons/Addons.php(1662): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#15 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Controller/Addons/Addons.php(946): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Addons\Addons->getModuleSettings('hop_deeploy_hel...', 'save', Array)
#16 [internal function]: EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Controller\Addons\Addons->settings('hop_deeploy_hel...', 'save')
#17 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(241): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#18 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Core/Core.php(110): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->runController(Array)
#19 ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.php(151): EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Core->run(Object(EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Core\Request))
#20 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
#20 admin.php(153): require_once('...')
```

Answer (score 1):

We sorted it out. The error always happened when we imported the db from the live server to the developer server and wanted to change there URLs and paths with Deeploy Helper.

After we reexported the db from the developer server and reimported it at either the two  dbs we got no error messages from Deploy Helper anymore.

It looks as if the db file from the live server had some strange content, because we also got rid of the problem mentioned in this entry [Saving takes minutes - Timeout when saving an edited entry](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/41741/saving-takes-minutes-timeout-when-saving-an-edited-entry/41759#41759) at the same time.

What exactly the reason for this trouble was is unknown.

I also want to add that a copy of the live site we installed on a complete new server place produced the same problem. Only importing to the original developer server did remove the trouble and let us save normally. And the exported db from that developer place did also remove the problem on the lave site and on the fresh installed copy on another server.

This was a very special experience where I am not able to understand why and how such things can happen.

Comment: Glad it worked out, Werner

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware Deeploy helper only works with EE3, there may have been some changes in EE5 that stop it working.

I suggest dropping https://www.hopstudios.com an email to see if they can fix it.

Comment: Deeploy Helper works with EE2 to EE5, though we're only adding new features for the EE3 and above version. We are looking into this issue now. https://www.hopstudios.com/software/hop_deeploy_helper/docs#version_history

Comment: @Travis, are there any insights what happens in my case with this error messages?